# Как имитировать событие для отладки?

Tags: c#

Код

```
System.Timers.Timer  t2 = new System.Timers.Timer() ;
t2.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent0;
//OnTimedEvent0 должен быть :
public void OnTimedEvent0(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e);
```

Как вызвать OnTimedEvent0?

```
Инициализация Arg1,Arg2;
OnTimedEvent0(Arg1, Arg2);
```

Comment: Минусаторы, слабо инициализировать параметры? А ну, создайте экземпляр `ElapsedEventArgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не так прост, как кажется.

Конечно, если нужно просто вызвать событие, то достаточно написать (как уже указано в комментарии):

```
OnTimedEvent0(null, null);
```

Но что, если в обработчике события эти параметры как-то используются?

Первым параметром нужно передать экземпляр таймера, который возбуждает это событие:

```
OnTimedEvent0(t2, null);
```

А вот со вторым есть проблема: класс `ElapsedEventArgs` имеет закрытый конструктор и его экземпляр невозможно создать напрямую.

Используем рефлексию. Пример кода взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43619543/5045688

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

```
var signalTime = DateTime.Now;

var e = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(ElapsedEventArgs)) as ElapsedEventArgs;
if (e != null)
{
    var fieldInfo = e.GetType().GetField("signalTime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fieldInfo != null)
    {
        fieldInfo.SetValue(e, signalTime);
    }
}
```

Теперь можно вызвать

```
OnTimedEvent0(t2, e);
```

---

Простите, погорячился. Сдуру ударился в рефлексию, позабыв про правильную архитектуру и всё такое.

Правильным решением будет следующее. Вся логика должна быть размещена в классе предметной модели. Или по крайней мере в отдельном методе. А в обработчике тика таймера просто вызываем этот метод.

```
// Обработчик события тика таймера
void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // просто вызываем другой метод
    ProcessTimerTick(...);
    // метод может быть размещён в другом классе,
    // тогда вызываем его у экземпляра того класса
    _timerProcessor.ProcessTimerTick(...);
}

void ProcessTimerTick(...)
{
    // здесь код обработки события таймера
}
```

Осталось определиться с сигнатурой метода.

Если нам не нужны данные от таймера, тогда делаем метод без параметров:

```
ProcessTimerTick()
```

Если данные нужны, то добавляем один или оба нужных параметра:

```
ProcessTimerTick(Timer timer, DateTime dateTime)
```

Вызываем метод, соответственно, так:

```
void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessTimerTick((Timer)sender, e.SignalTime);
}
```

Теперь, если нам нужно для какой-то цели вызвать этот метод, например, для модульного тестирования, то это делается легко и просто. И не нужна рефлексия.

Comment: я не понял самого вопроса. теперь понятно: минус убран, коммент удалён

Comment: @return - автору, возможно, это и не нужно. Но пусть будет.

Comment: для общего развития как раз очень нужно.